# Passar id de pagina html dentro de ngFor para pagina ts

Tags: angular, ionic2, typescript

Tenho um *ngFor de um objeto array, quero passar o id dentro do button para o typescript para configuralos como links em um modal. Segue a sintaxe que estou tentando sem exito:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of itens">
    <ion-thumbnail item-left>
      <img src="../assets/img/{{item.img}}">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <h2>{{item.nome}}</h2>
    <p>{{item.categ}}</p>
    <button id="{{item.id}}" ion-button clear item-right (click)="chamaProd()">ver</button>
  </ion-item>
```

Comment: e o controlador do componente? que código tem ?

Comment: Seria apenas (click)="chamaProd(item.id)", assim no seu controller a função ficaria chamaProd(id) e esse id é o que foi passado. Já tentou isso? Se quiser faço um exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente fazer dessa forma:

HTML:

```
 (click)="chamaProd(item)"
```

Assim você vai passar o objeto completo da lista para o seu método `chamaProd`.

TS:

```
  chamaProd(item : <<Objeto da Lista>>){
.
. /* No corpo do metodo vc faz oque quiser, pois, vc tem a instancia do objeto clicado em tela */
}
```